# MPAndroidChart Android Studio Errors while building APK

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I was trying some tutorials about MPAndroidChart and its worked so well in my emulator. But when I try to build the APK, I've got two errors ...

> "Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/github/mikephil/charting/BuildConfig;"
>
> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2"

can someone help me ...

this is my build.gradle script

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myname.lesson03"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile  ('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you have the same library/directory included more than once in your build.gradle's dependencies.

My suggestion is to check your 'libs' folder. Make sure you only reference MPAndroidChart once.

Also, try to comment out this line:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Comment: clean project and remove/ make as comment that line as you suggested .. and its working ..  thanks man.